# StackExchange.Redis - Implement Expire on Hashset or search keys - good performance

Tags: c#, .net, caching, redis, stackexchange.redis

I have redis cache use by StackExchange.Redis.

firstly, the redis contain hashSets and i try to set a expire for key in hashSet , but i read this (https://github.com/antirez/redis/issues/167#issuecomment-2559040) and realized that it is not possible.

so i change my redis cache and now it contain only key , value pair.
The problem for expire was actually solved :-).

but another functionality of the cache is to **get all key start with some** **prefix**.

firstly i try to use Keys function , but it is not recommneded here and i get timeout exception in some of the case.

After reading i choose to use StackExchange.Redis.Extention.Core that contain function SearchKey(string pattren).
(see https://www.nuget.org/packages/StackExchange.Redis.Extensions.Core)

the SearchKey function work fine , the only problem is a bad performance.

for 50,0000 key the searchKey function take : 3~ seconds.

for 100,0000 key the searchKey function take : 6~ seconds.

for 200,0000 key the searchKey function take : 12~ seconds.

In production my redis cache will conatain **200,000 - 300,000 Keys** so this is bad performance..

Any ideas , to solve it?

Thank!

Comment: Actually you have answered your question by your self. Redis does not provides direct ability to set expiration on individual keys inside hashset. But fastest way to scan range of keys in db (MGETALL or SCAN 0 MATCH * COUNT 10000 or KEYS) does not satisfies your requirements. But you still can store list of your keys in "list" or "hashset" with TTL specified. You can use KeyExpire() for this.